# Como ampliar el conocimiento de mi red neuronal convolucional

Tags: python, tensorflow, redes-neuronales, keras, inteligencia-artificial

Estoy comenzando con la inteligencia artificial y tengo una red neuronal convolucional (cnn) sencilla, la cual diferencia imágenes entre gatos, perros y gorilas. Mi pregunta es:

**¿Cómo puedo añadir mil imágenes más a cada tipo sin tener que volver a entrenar con todas las imágenes?**

Es decir, 1000 más de gatos, 1000 más de perros y 1000 más de gorilas, , entrenando solamente con las 1000 nuevas de cada tipo (3000 en total) y ajustando los pesos que ya tiene, sin tener que volver a calcularlo todo, este es mi código:

```
import sys
import os
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.python.keras import optimizers, layers, models
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense, Activation
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K

K.clear_session()
data_train = './img/entrenamiento'
data_test = './img/test'

epochs = 20
steps_per_epoch = 1000
altura, longitud = 100, 100
batch_size = 32
steps_validation = 200
filtroConv1 = 32
filtroConv2 = 64
filtroConv1_size = (3,3)
filtroConv2_size = (2,2)
pool_size = (2,2)
tipos_imagen = 3
lr = 0.0005
train_labels = ['perro', 'gato', 'gorila']
test_labels = ['perro', 'gato', 'gorila']

entrenamiento_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1./255,
    shear_range = 0.2,
    zoom_range = 0.2,
    horizontal_flip = True
)

validacion_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1./255
)

train_images = entrenamiento_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    data_train,
    target_size = (altura, longitud),
    batch_size = batch_size,
    class_mode = 'categorical'
)

test_images = validacion_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    data_test,
    target_size = (altura, longitud),
    batch_size = batch_size,
    class_mode = 'categorical'
)

cnn = models.Sequential()

cnn.add(Convolution2D(filtroConv1, filtroConv1_size, padding = 'same', input_shape = (altura, longitud, 3), activation = 'relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = pool_size))

cnn.add(Convolution2D(filtroConv2, filtroConv2_size, padding = 'same'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = pool_size))

cnn.add(Flatten())
cnn.add(Dense(256, activation = 'relu'))

cnn.add(Dropout(0.5))
cnn.add(Dense(tipos_imagen, activation = 'softmax'))

cnn.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = lr), metrics = ['accuracy'])

history = cnn.fit(train_images, epochs = epochs, validation_data = test_images)

print(train_images.class_indices)

dir = './model/'

if not os.path.exists(dir):
    os.mkdir(dir) 
    
cnn.save('./model/model.h5')
cnn.save_weights('./model/pesos.h5')
```

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo decirle que entrene otra vez, pero solamente con las 1000 imágenes nuevas de cada tipo y que actualice los pesos que ya tiene calculados? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basandome sobre tu código, tienes que hacer los siguiente pasos:

1. Cargas las **solo las imágenes nuevas** como lo has hecho en tu código con las antiguas
2. Hacer/aplicar el mismo pre-procesamiento de datos que hicistes con las imágenes antiguas (en tu caso los generadores)
3. Definir la misma red neuronal que tenías definida, es decir tu objeto `cnn` con las mismas capas e hiper-parámetros que tenían.
4. Una vez tienes la red neuronal definida le cargas los pesos que tienes guardados usando el método `.load_weights()`. En tu caso sería `cnn.load_weights("ruta/delos/pesos.h5")`
5. Por último, llamas al método `.fit()` pasandole las imágenes nuevas como ya has hecho.

Matemáticamente lo que estamos haciendo es que ya teníamos unos pesos calculados en la red neuronal, simplemente queremos seguir entrenando a partir de esos pesos. Es decir, **en vez de inicializar la red neuronal con pesos aleatorios, la inicias con unos pesos, que tu ya sabes que son buenos** (porque lo has entrenado previamente) y sigues a partir de ahí.

### Advertencia

Es importante que **NO haya un sesgo** entre las anteriores imágenes (datos) y las nuevas, ya que si entregamos datos con distinta varianza, realmente lo que hacemos es **desaprender patrones** para aprender otros nuevos, por lo que tu red neuronal funcionará peor en el primer conjunto de datos.

La anterior explicación en hechos significa, que no puedes hacer que en la segunda tanda de imágenes las fotos sean más oscuras, o que todos los gorilas estén de perfil, cuando en el primer entrenamiento estabán de frente, etc.

Si el segundo conjunto de datos está sesgado con respecto al primero de alguna forma, **debes** juntar todos los datos y **reentrenar de nuevo** con todos los **datos barajados de manera aleatoría**, para que tu red neuronal sea capaz de capturar toda la varianza y generalizar.

Comment: Y todo lo demás lo dejo tal cual?? sin cambiar nada? quiero decir, lo único que tendría que hacer es antes del fit(), poner el .load_weights() y lo demás se queda igual? Y Muchas gracias por la aportación

Comment: Sí, de hecho si lo cambias no te funcionará, ya que si cambias la red neuronal no podrás cargar los pesos y si no haces el mismo preprocesado de datos igual, estarías tu mismo sesgando los distintos conjuntos de imágenes.

Comment: De hecho verás que tu métrica de `accuracy` en  la primera iteración será muy alta, debido a que ya tienes unos pesos que son  muy buenos puesto que han sido entrenados.

Comment: Perfecto y de nuevo muchas gracias por la ayuda, estoy empezando y estos consejos ayudan bastante.

Comment: Y una duda que acaba de surgirme, al pasarle las imágenes nuevas, tengo que eliminar las viejas?? O las añado junto a las que ya tenía?? Muchas gracias

Comment: No sé si he entendido bien este comentario, pero es lo que te he indicado en la respuesta, *solo las imágenes nuevas*. si le vuelves a pasar todas las imagenes de nuevo no tendría sentido mi respuesta porque no se adecuaría a tu pregunta.

Comment: Okey, muchas gracias!!!